# how to delete a shared object by clicking a button in a listview

Tags: android

I have a disPlayScore() method, and now want to create a deleteScore() method for each button in the listview.

Below is my current code:

```
    private void disPlayScore() {
    if (scores.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(HighScore.this, "Không có điểm nào được lưu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        getHighScoreListFromSharedPreference();
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(HighScore.this, R.layout.list_row, scores);
        list_core.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a item click listener to your list view like this:

```
list_core.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.remove("score"); // Put your score key in the preferences here
            editor.apply();
      }
   });
```

That will remove the score if any item is clicked, you can change that by checking the `position`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a button in each row view. As each row gets created, you simply associate a method that will delete the item in that row view, you can do this with event handlers, in the adapter itself, etc. There are many ways to go about this task.

For example, each row has a score, and a remove button, as the rows get created in the adapter, you specify that each rowviews "remove button" has an event to remove the item, here's some dummy code to get the idea across:

```
myRowViewRemoveButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    scores.Remove(this.score);
}
```